# Use of the parameter "out" without assigning <variable>

Tags: c#, methods

The following code has an error:

> Use of the parameter "out" without assigning 'backup'

```
public void StartProgram()
{
    string backup = " ";
    NewContact(backup: out backup);
}

void NewContact(out string backup)
{
    string contact = "Bob";
    backup = backup + contact; // Error here
}
```

I can't figure out where the problem is, the method `NewContact(out string backup)` is using `out` parameters.
 So, when the method is finished it is supposed to set a new value to the variable storage in the `StartProgram()` method.

( the variable is used to store all the contacts that are being created)

Comment: What line is that error referring to?

Comment: In future, please specify exactly which line of code an error occurs on.  We shouldn't have to trawl through code to find information that you already know.

Comment: Use ref read article by link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref

Comment: Please take a look at my  edit and [MCVE] guidance and for future questions post more concise code.

Answer (score 4):

The `out` keyword denotes a parameter that is used for output only and not input.  As such, the first usage of a parameter declare `out` **must** be an assignment.  In your `NewContact` method, the first use of the `backup` parameter is here:

```
backup = backup + contact;
```

That code concatenates `backup` and `contact` and then assigns the result to `backup`.  That means that your first use of the `backup` parameter is a concatenation, which is not an assignment and is thus not allowed.

Why are you trying to concatenate something that has no useful value at that point?  If you expect that `backup` could have a value at that point then the parameter must be being used as input as well as output and should thus be declared `ref` rather than `out`.

Answer (score 0):

As per **Out** Keyword Uses in C# , We need to assign the variable in Called Method(`NewContact`) then use for manipulation. So You could code like below:

```
void NewContact(out string backup)
{
    backup = string.Empty; // Or any value that your logic needs.
    string contact = SnapsEngine.ReadString("Enter the contact name");
    string address = SnapsEngine.ReadMultiLineString("Enter " + contact + " address");
    string number = SnapsEngine.ReadString("Enter " + contact + " number");
    Storeinfo(contact: contact, address: address, number: number);
    backup = backup + contact;

    SnapsEngine.WaitForButton("Continue");
}
```

Comment: While that code would remove the error, it's a rather silly solution. Why would you assign an empty `string` to the parameter just so that you could use it in a concatenation?  Why not just NOT use it in the concatenation?  If declaring that parameter `out` is appropriate then the solution to the problem is not to assign a dummy value to it first but rather change `backup = backup + contact;` to `backup = contact;`.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Ya Sure. I just suggested the way he can handle the issue. I added the comment also the value of `backup` should depend upon the requirement he has.